# How many liters of each acidic solution should be mixed?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Chris needs to make 500 L of a 35% acidic solution. He has only two of the acidic solutions available,a 25% solution and a 50% solution. How many liters of each acidic solution should he mix? (Solve by substitution)

Comment: I have voted to close this question as "lacking context," because it appears to be a problem that has been copied and pasted to the website. You can read [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/120540) about what *context* means in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

We have $500$ liters of solution and a $175$ liters of solute.

Let $A$ and $B$ be the amount of solution mixed.

$A+B=500$

$0.25A+0.5B=175$

Then we have $A=500-B$.

Therefore, $0.25(500-B)+0.5B=175$.

Then $125-0.25B+0.5B=175$.

Then, we have $125+0.25B=175$, so $B=200$.

Therefore, $A=300$ and $B =200$.

The equations match this too.

Therefore, $300$ liters of $25\%$ solution and $200$ liters of $50\%$ solution were mixed to form $500$ liters of $35\%$ solution.